# Overlap Error (possible subnetting mistake)

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

```
Device  Interface   Number of Hosts Subnet  Subnet Mask

London
        Fa0/0         30           193.10.156.0     255.255.255.224
        Fa0/1         20           193.10.156.32    255.255.255.224
        S0/0/1        2            193.10.156.64    255.255.255.252
        S0/0/0        2            193.10.156.68    255.255.255.252

Edinburgh   
        Fa0/0         10           193.10.156.72    255.255.255.240
        Fa0/1         15           193.10.156.88    255.255.255.224
        S0/0/1        2            193.10.156.64    255.255.255.252
Cardiff 
        Fa0/0         14           193.10.156.120   255.255.255.224
        Fa0/1         8            193.10.156.136   255.255.255.240
        S0/0/0        2            193.10.156.68    255.255.255.252


Device  Interface   IP Address  Subnet Mask Default Gateway

London  
    Fa0/0   193.10.156.1    255.255.255.224 N/A
    Fa0/1   193.10.156.33   255.255.255.224 N/A
    S0/0/1  193.10.156.65   255.255.255.252 N/A
    S0/0/0  193.10.156.69   255.255.255.252 N/A
    Lo0     183.32.43.254   255.255.255.252 N/A
Edinburgh
    Fa0/0   193.10.156.73   255.255.255.240 N/A
    Fa0/1   193.10.156.89   255.255.255.224 N/A
    S0/0/1  193.10.156.66   255.255.255.252 N/A

Cardiff
    Fa0/0   193.10.156.121  255.255.255.224 N/A
    Fa0/1   193.10.156.137  255.255.255.240 N/A
    S0/0/0  193.10.156.70   255.255.255.252 N/A
    PC1     193.10.156.30   255.255.255.224 193.10.156.1
    PC2     193.10.156.62   255.255.255.224 193.10.156.33
    PC3     193.10.156.86   255.255.255.240 193.10.156.73
    PC4     193.10.156.118  255.255.255.224 193.10.156.89
    PC5     193.10.156.134  255.255.255.240 193.10.156.137
    PC6     193.10.156.150  255.255.255.224 193.10.156.121
```

[image]

The FA interface will get the first usable IP address and the PCs will get the last one.

I get an error when i do the addressing the overlap error. Did i do something wrong on the addressing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overlapping networks for London and Edinburgh.

London:

```
    S0/0/1        2            193.10.156.64    255.255.255.252
    S0/0/0        2            193.10.156.68    255.255.255.252
```

Overlaps with Edinburgh:

```
    Fa0/0         10           193.10.156.72    255.255.255.240
```

If you mask the Edinburgh `193.10.156.72` with `255.255.2555.240` you get a subnet address of `193.10.156.64`.

```
193.10.156.72   = 11000001.00001010.10011100.01001000
255.255.255.240 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.11110000
                  ===================================
                  11000001.00001010.10011100.01000000 = 193.10.156.64
```

You can't just make up a subnet address and mask like `193.10.156.72 255.255.255.240`, you actually should mask the address to see if you got the subnet. In this case, you didn't.

Comment: May i ask one more thing ? Are the IP addreses ok ? apart the masks

Comment: I didn't go through all your addresses in detail; I just spotted an error, and I gave you what you should do to make sure they are all OK. What you have are public IP addresses, and I don't know how big your block is.

Comment: im sorry but i just cant undestand  it for F0/0 i need 10 hosts so the host id is 4 and the network id is also 4 so = 193.10.156.72 /28 and mask 255.255.255.240 i know that you said and prouved that 240 is not the mask but i just dont get it. what do i count wrong ?

Comment: A subnet needs to start at an address which is a multiple of the host portion of the mask. Your mask `255.255.255.240` allows for 16 addresses in the host portion. That means the subnet address must begin on a number evenly divisible by 16, and `193.10.156.72` is not. 64 and 80 are evenly divisible by 16, so the next subnet of that size would need to use 80. Think about why you couldn't use 64 and 66 for the serial links; it is the same reason, they overlap. You you will have a gap in addresses which you can use, but it is often that way. You must look at this stuff in binary to see it.